# Django scheduling, how to check if date is between two dates

Tags: django, date, schedule

Currently i'm working on another booking project. Here is my reservation model:

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null = True, blank = True)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service)
    starttime = models.DateTimeField('reservation start')
    endtime = models.DateTimeField('reservation end')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"Nr: %s" % self.id
```

Here is how i imagine my app should work - User chooses employee. User chooses service(duration depends on specific service). Then user chooses date on calendar. Now date is passed to method that checks in 30 minutes intervals if chosen employee is available. Then all available reservation times are displayed. For example:

> ```
> Employee choice:
> John Doe
> Service choice:
> Air Filter Replacement
> Duration: 1 hour
> Date picked:
> 30/06/2016
> Available reservation time:
> 12:30 - 13:30
> 15:30 - 16:30 
> 17:00 - 18:00
>
> Employee choice:
> John Doe
> Service choice:
> Suction Manifold Flaps Removal
> Duration: 2 hours
> Date picked:
> 1/07/2016
> Available reservation time:
> 13:00 - 15:00 
> 17:00 - 19:00
> ```

This is a huge roadblock for me since i don't have any good idea how to approach this.

My first idea was that i could take date chosen by user, employee id, duration and iterate through working hours every 30 minutes in while loop:

```
time_interval = 30  #interval
working_day_start = 10  #starts working at 10 am
working_day_end = 20    #ends working at 8 pm
duration = service_duration  #how long service takes
start = choosen_date + datetime.timedelta(hours = working_day_start)
end = choosen_date + datetime.timedelta(hours = working_day_end)
availibility_table = []

while start <= end – datetime.timedelta(hours = duration):
    is_available = employee.isAvailable(start, employee_id, duration)
    if is_available:
        availibility_date = [start, start + datetime.timedelta(hours = duration)]
        availibility_table.append(availibility_date)
    start += datetime.timedelta(minutes = time_interval)
return availability_table
```

As you can see i'd need employee.isAvailable function and i don't know how to write it. Basically it would have to tell me if in time between start and start+duration said employee is already assigned to any reservations.

Also is that approach correct and optimal? Is there an easier way to achieve what i need?

EDIT:

Here is my Employee model. It is as simple as it gets.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank = False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank = False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

Comment: Can you add your `Employee` schema to the post? It may help.

Comment: @MiteshNinja I added Employee model. It is as simple as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
def isAvailable(start, employee_id, duration):
    employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=employee_id)
    # See if the employee has any reservations that overlap
    # with this window. The logic here is that the *start* of
    # the reservation is before the *end* of the time period we
    # are checking, and the *end* of the reservation is after the
    # *start* of the time period we are checking.
    this_period_end = start + datetime.timedelta(hours=duration)
    existing_reservations = employee.reservation_set.filter(
        starttime__lte=this_period_end,
        endtime__gte=start
    )

    # If we found matches, then the employee is busy for some part of
    # this period
    return not existing_reservations.exists()
```

It does mean doing a query for every period that you want to test. Conceptually I feel like there must be a more efficient solution but it eludes me at present. In any case, you should be able to refine it once you confirm that this logic works.

Comment: It seems to work, but apparently i had to change lte and gte operators to lt and gt. Otherwise there was 30 minutes offset. Great answer i really appreciate your help!